# Infinit loop when I 'print_r' variables like $form_state, $form

Tags: 8

I don't understand, I want show some vars during my dev. I work on windows and Linux.

On windows, When I use print_r for show $form or $form_state (from the hook form_alter). There isn't any problem, when the page is loaded, I can see the content of theses vars.

But on linux, when I use print_r, I see the RAM (via top/htop) rise continuously until 4Go and my OS freeze x) The page I request is never loaded.

I don't understand because I don't think have a special configuration. My configuration is recent.

On Linux (Mint)

php -v : 5.6.14
apache2 -v : 2.4.10 (Raspbian)

**Solution**

Activate the sub-extend drupal Kint from the devel package :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not like the answer, but it's still true: Don't use print_r() for $form/$form_state, entity or other complex objects. It just doesn't work.

Try kint() from the devel module instead, make sure to install the kint submodule too.

Comment: Devel (dpm) use print_r =) And I get infinit loop when I use dpm with $form, $form_state..

Comment: That's why I said kint() and not dpm().

Comment: kint() is not a replacement for dpm(), because dpm() uses drupal message to store the debug output in a session and to show it on the next page, that is loaded. Perfect would be a dpm that uses kint instead of kprint_r.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks guys ! I see the sub-extend (of devel) kint wasn't actived. When I actived it, I finally can show contents of form, form_state...